# Values aren't being computed

Tags: java, floating-point, int, calculation

I'm trying to design a simple method, however the values aren't being calculated for some reason:

```
public static void animateBattery()
{
    float boxPercent = (58/100);
    System.out.println( "boxPercent "+ boxPercent);

    int batteryPercent = (int) Math.round(storageLimit / 100 * elecStored);
    setBatteryColor(batteryPercent);
    System.out.println( "batteryPercent "+ batteryPercent);

    int storedPercent = (int) Math.round(boxPercent * batteryPercent);
    System.out.println( "storedPercent "+ storedPercent);

    System.out.println( "Another demonstration " + 58/100);

    System.out.println( "One more " + 100);

    batteryColor.setBounds(890, 405 + (58 - storedPercent), 81, storedPercent);
    frame.getContentPane().add(batteryColor);
}
```

outputs:

```
boxPercent 0.0
batteryPercent 0
storedPercent 0
Another demonstration 0
One more 100
```

Hope I've provided enough code to go off. Apologies for being a noob. Any assistance with this would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: `(58/100)` is an integer arithmetic function before it gets casted to `float`. So it is `0`.

Comment: By default with integer operands you get an integer division, consider having at least one of your operands of type `float` .

Comment: Thanks for your help guys!

Comment: `58 / 100 == 0` but `58 % 100 == 58` which is the remainder.